# Remove Handler to Button

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove a handler (Click) from a button, I tried many ways but they didn't work.

I create two buttons like this:

```
private void CreateButtons()
{
    Button button1 = new Button()
    {
        Text = "Start"
    };
    Button button2 = new Button()
    {
        Text = "Stop"
    };
    this.Controls.Add(button1);
    button1.Click += Button1_Click;
    this.Controls.Add(button2);
    button2.Click += Button2_Click;
}
```

The first one just creates a MessageBox:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
}
```

The second one should remove the handler:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Click -= Button1_Click;
}
```

Unfortunately after clicking button2, button1 keeps generating a MessageBox. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is your Button2_Click event getting a the button1 object? It looks like you're creating them in your CreateButtons method, so I'm not sure where the reference is coming from.

Comment: I think you have a separate button in your form named `button1` which is not the button you're creating.

Comment: You have button1 defined inside CreateButtons so you must have two instances of Button1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your form has a different button you've created at an earlier time named `button1`.

Remove that, and make your `button1` and `button2` fields of the form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CreateButtons()
    {
        button1 = new Button()
        {
            Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 10, FontStyle.Bold),
            BackColor = Color.Yellow,
            Width = 79,
            Height = 62,
            Location = new Point(141, 191),
            Text = "Start"
        };

        button2 = new Button()
        {
            Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 10, FontStyle.Bold),
            BackColor = Color.Yellow,
            Width = 79,
            Height = 62,
            Location = new Point(338, 191),
            Text = "Stop"
        };
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
        button1.Click += Button1_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(button2);
        button2.Click += Button2_Click;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Click -= Button1_Click;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateButtons();
    }
}
```

Comment: That was actually my problem! In my designer there was the code of a previous button1. Thanks for the help